# Pandas Cannot Filter Our nan Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have no idea why this isn't working... Why am I not able to get rid of these?

I have tried the following:

```
dfa = dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'].str.len() < 4] #empty
dfa = dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'] != ''] #no change
dfa = dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'] != np.nan] #no change
```

Dtype is string, and sample values below:

```
['May-30-2018', nan, nan, 'June-11-2014', 'December-3-2021', nan, 'February-2-2022', nan, nan, 'December-30-2011', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'November-30-2021', nan, 'April-1-2020', nan, 'May-10-2007', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'January-28-2022', nan, nan, nan, 'January-18-2022', nan, nan, nan, 'January-12-2022', nan, 'November-15-2021'
```

Comment: None of those would filter nan values. [np.nan != np.nan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/15497888) is always a true statement by definition of NaN. You probably mean `dfa = dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'].notna()]` or even `dfa = dfa.dropna(subset=['Date Sold_y'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe `nan` values are string with extra whitespaces:

```
>>> dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'].str.strip() != 'nan']
         Date Sold_y
0        May-30-2018
3       June-11-2014
4    December-3-2021
6    February-2-2022
9   December-30-2011
18  November-30-2021
20      April-1-2020
22       May-10-2007
29   January-28-2022
33   January-18-2022
37   January-12-2022
39  November-15-2021
```

2. You can also reverse the logic and keep rows ended by a year:

```
>>> dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'].str.contains('\d{4}$')]
```

3. Or if it's really `nan` values, as suggested by @HenryEcker:

```
>>> dfa[dfa['Date Sold_y'].notna()]

# OR

>>> dfa[~dfa['Date Sold_y'].isna()]
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way if the values are actually nan (and not strings) check out the `dropna()` method of `pandas.DataFrame`. It allows to drop rows of the dataframe if one or more nan is found (you can chose) or you can specify a subset of columns to check against nan values